# how to check if fragment_cache exists in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a slim fragment like this:

```
- cache [@user, :user_show, 'v2'] do
```

but we are concerned about our hit / miss rate and would like to log this. Is there an easy way to do this? I was thinking I could could `Rails.cache.exist?` but I'd need to know more than what I have here (namely the template digest). Any ideas how to check for the existence of a cached fragment?

Comment: You can use the `Rails.cache.read` method. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper.html#method-i-cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `controller.fragment_exist?` for that https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/AbstractController/Caching/Fragments/fragment_exist%3F

And you should be able to use `cache_fragment_name` to get the actual key https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper/cache_fragment_name

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod - I think it's [`fragment_exist?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/AbstractController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-fragment_exist-3F) -- tried to edit but i couldn't.